# Regex for validating the Civil ID in Swift for the UITextField

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have got a UITextfield with the following format . It is a Civil ID which we usually get to see in Gulf Countries. So I need to validate the same in my UITextfield in Swift.

Civil ID format - NYYMMDDNNNNN where N a digit, YY last two digits of birth year, MM birth month, DD birth date..

Please tell me how to do validation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example how to use the regex

```
var civilID = "4 88 05 20 8787"
var isValidCivilID: Bool {
    do {
        // the first 0 (?!00) checks that the numbers should not be all zero and d{2} it should have 2 digigts remember it's simple you can make it much complex
        // also if you want space in between or not
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d{1} (?!00)\\d{2} (?!00)\\d{2} (?!00)\\d{2} (?!0000)\\d{4}", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: civilID, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, civilID.characters.count)) != nil
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

if your not checking agains a format then remove the spaces in the regex as well if civilID is correctly filled it will return true else false

if you want to add these checks in String extensions and read some more please refer to this link [Swift Extensions, extending Strings](https://www.swiftyninja.com/swift-extensions-extending-strings-extension/)

Comment: it is not working i guess

Comment: did you tried to read there in link as well

Comment: I think the regex is not correct ... I am getting false in return and more over i need to check 88 05 20 in "4 88 05 20 8787" is in yymmdd format.

Comment: Please look to it and clarify the error and kindly post the correct answer.

Comment: @JessicaRoot check the regex I had missed and added had the check for only 4 88 05 8787 now added one more which is 4 88 05 20 8787

Comment: Thanks i found it but still its returning false..

Comment: add this 2 slashes in the beginning as well which I had missed `\\d{1}`